Find maximum length of consecutive zeros in each row
My goal is to find the maximum length of consecutive zeros in each row. So for instance, if I have a tensor like
input = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

I expect to get the result
tensor([3, 2, 5])

I’ve done this using numpy (listed below assuming “input” is a numpy binary matrix) and it tends to be very efficient, but I cannot seem to find a way using tensors that is at least as efficient. I’ve tried to follow a similar logic using torch operations but the performance is always worse.
Thanks!
import numpy as np
input = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
# Pad the matrix with ones
padded_matrix = np.pad(input, ((0, 0), (1, 1)), constant_values=1)

# Compute differences
diffs = np.diff(padded_matrix, axis=1)

# Identify start and end of zero runs
start_indices = np.where(diffs == -1)
end_indices = np.where(diffs == 1)

#Compute lengths of zero runs
run_lengths = end_indices[1] - start_indices[1]

# Create a result array initialized with zeros
max_zeros = np.zeros(binaryGrid.shape[0], dtype=int)

# Use np.maximum.at to find the maximum run length for each row
np.maximum.at(max_zeros, start_indices[0], run_lengths)

print(max_zeros)


The rows contain only 0 and 1. Were they originally numbers? If so, it is much more efficient to solve this using bitwise operations.

Yes, the rows only contain 0s and 1s.

Why do you want to do this with tensors? Is that a restriction in the question or you just want an efficient algorithm?

Essentially I need tensors to perform Fast Fourier Transforms. As such, it would be nice to keep everything as tensors to avoid switching between tensors and numpy arrays (or any other data type). But it is not mandatory to do this with tensors.

For a torch implementation, you can use scatter_reduce in place of np.maximum.at
def test_np(x):
    padded_matrix = np.pad(x, ((0, 0), (1, 1)), constant_values=1)

    diffs = np.diff(padded_matrix, axis=1)

    start_indices = np.where(diffs == -1)
    end_indices = np.where(diffs == 1)
    run_lengths = end_indices[1] - start_indices[1]

    max_zeros = np.zeros(x.shape[0], dtype=int)
    np.maximum.at(max_zeros, start_indices[0], run_lengths)
    return max_zeros

def test_torch(x):
    padded_matrix = F.pad(x, (1,1), value=1)
    diffs = torch.diff(padded_matrix, axis=1)
    
    start_indices = torch.where(diffs==-1)
    end_indices = torch.where(diffs == 1)
    run_lengths = end_indices[1] - start_indices[1]
    max_zeros = torch.zeros(x.shape[0]).long().scatter_reduce(
        dim=0,
        index=start_indices[0],
        src=run_lengths,
        reduce='amax'
    )

    return max_zeros

rows = 12
cols = 32
thresh = 0.5
x_torch = (torch.rand(rows, cols)>thresh).long()
x_np = x_torch.numpy()

result_torch = test_torch(x_torch)
result_np = test_np(x_np)

Benchmarking on my system both versions give equivalent performance on CPU.

You might want to clarify your imports (specifically, I believe F is referring to torch.nn.functional).

Yes that's correct

This. This is correct. Best is to use PyTorch's scatter_reduce to efficiently find the maximum length.

I don't have torch installed, but I guess you can borrow the idea below by using numpy and string.split
np.array(
    [
        max(np.vectorize(len)(s.split("1")))
        for s in np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: "".join(x), 1, input.astype(str))
    ]
)

which should give
array([3, 2, 5])


This solution is based on bitwise operations:
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ])
COLS = a.shape[1]
LEFT = (1<<COLS)-1

def get_max_zeros(x):
    r = 0
    l = LEFT                    # 1s in the number of 0s when the loop is break
    while True:
        if x:
            b = (x^(x-1))//2    # Set trailing 0s to 1s and zero rest
            r |= b              # Find the maximum
            p = 2*(b+1)         # 2 to the power of  number of 0s + 1
            x //= p             # Right shift by the number of 0s + 1
            l //= p             # Right shift by the number of 0s + 1
        else:
            r |= l              # Find the maximum
            break
    return r.bit_count()

max_zeros = np.array(list(map(
    get_max_zeros,
    np.sum(a*[1<<c for c in range(COLS)], axis=1))))

print(max_zeros)

It works for an unlimited number of binary digits. I stopped checking when I reached the value of 10000.

Thank you for your suggestion! From a quick performance check this option seems to be about 10x slower than the one I've shown with numpy operations for matrices of the type a = np.random.randint(0, 2, (random.randint(10, 215),random.randint(250, 400))). I might be wrong but I believe that for smaller matrices this option might be better, but its performance degrades quickly with the size of the matrix

Thank you for considering my solution. Converting columns with values of 0 and 1 only to a number takes a lot of time, which can be eliminated if the data is initially packed into bits of integers. I just wanted to solve your problem, as it is very suitable for bitwise operations and may still be useful to you.

A numpy based answer which may point to a tensor flow one.
A line by line version:
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

arr_eq0 = arr ^ 1  # Invert the apr

cum0s = arr_eq0.cumsum(axis = 1 )   # Cumulative zero count

cum0s
# array([[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4],
#        [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

cum_steps = cum0s * arr       # Zero where arr == 0

cum_steps
# array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4],
#        [0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

cum_steps = np.maximum.accumulate( cum_steps, axis = 1 )

cum_steps    # Flat line where arr== 0
# array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4],
#        [0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

cum0s - cum_steps    # The difference is the cumulative run of zeroes within each run of zeros
# array([[1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
#        [1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])

(cum0s - cum_steps).max( axis = 1 )  # Max by row
# array([3, 2, 5])

As a function:
def longest_zero_run( arr ):
    arr_eq0 = arr ^ 1
    cum0s = arr_eq0.cumsum(axis = 1 )
    cum_steps = np.maximum.accumulate( cum0s * arr, axis = 1 )
    return (cum0s - cum_steps).max( axis = 1 )

